# Scalable Videos Not Making Grid

Tags: html, css

I have these videos that I'm trying to lay in a grid. Every video would be 25%, so there would be 4 videos in a row. This is what I got.

```
.qtvideo {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:25px;
    height:0;
}
.qtvideo iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:25%;
    height:25%;
}
```

Then my HTML.

```
<div class="qtvideo">
<iframe width="960" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="qtvideo">
<iframe width="960" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I don't get why they're no laying next to each other.

Comment: I don't really get what your saying but do you mean like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/H2U2D/)

Comment: @Ruddy just like that! Lol, I guess I just over thought this one..

Comment: Haha want me to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said you did over think it. Just need 4 divs at `25%` width and the iframes in there with `100%` of both width and height. Then float the divs left. Done!

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/link" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/H2U2D/1/)

Comment: One problem, the videos seem kind of squashed. The width is there, but the height is weird.

Comment: Chnage the `div` height now as that's controlling the iframes height and width.

Comment: Nm, just had to add a "width" perimeter